# Update document title by props from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have Main component in my app, there I have method to set document title. Component looks like:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setTitle(this.props.title);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.title !== this.props.title) {
      this.setTitle(newProps.title);
    }
  }

  setTitle = (title) => {
    document.title = title;
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

usage:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Main><AppContent /></Main>;
  }
}
```

And now I want to set the document title in the child components (AppContent and children of that component). Problem is I have Main component in storybook repo and I can't use redux in the index file of Main component (I can do it in App component and others, but I never used redux before). Anyone can give me a hint how I should pass title from other components? 
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in a nice clean way I have used `react-helmet` by the NFL (yes the NFL).

https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

With `react-helmet` you can do the following in any child component, nested at any level:

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

<ChildComponent>
    <Helmet>
        <title>react-helmet will make this the title</title>
    </Helmet>
</ChildComponent>
```